# WPF DataGrid. Сохранить изменения в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Загружаем в DataGrid данные 
                    `var result = db.Sports.AsEnumerable().ToList();
                    dataGrid.ItemsSource = result;`

Данные отображаются. После редактирования сохранить назад в entity framework.
db.SaveChanges(); Сохраняет только измененные данные, а не вновь добавленные или удаленные.

```
  public class Sports : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _sport;

    public string sport
    {
        get
        {
            return _sport;
        }
        set
        {
            _sport = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("sport");
        }
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int sports_code { get; set; }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }      
}
```

Comment: У вас данные не добавляются в контекст `EF`, поэтому и не сохраняет.

Comment: а как добавить? db.Sports.Add(new Sports());  ругается что есть такой обьект

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Sports objToAdd;` **// получим объект который был изменен**

```
 private void dataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        objToAdd = dataGrid.SelectedItem as Sports;

        //Проверим если такой же в сущности:
        var conn = db.Sports.Where(c => c.sports_code == objToAdd.sports_code).FirstOrDefault();
        if (conn == null)
        {                       
            db.Sports.Add(objToAdd);
        }
        else
        {
            conn.sports_code = objToAdd.sports_code;
            conn.sport = objToAdd.sport;
            db.Entry(conn).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

[Тут нашел подсказку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434070/save-a-new-datagrid-row-to-database)